# Chartjs: dynamic data (array) not working

Tags: jquery, chart.js

In my recent work, I'm implementing ChartJS charts.
But I'm having trouble popularizing the graph with the data I get from the database.

**What I am trying to do:**
I get the data from the database, and I send the information I want for an Array.

And I'm pulling the Array in the field I want to use.

**Here is my code js:**

```
function charts(){
var ligEntrantes = [];
var registeredOrders = [];
var duvidasRegistradas = [];
var incidentesRegistrados = [];

$.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url("/relatorios/auxiliar")?>',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        $(response.information).each(function(index, item){
            ligEntrantes.push(item.incomingCalls);
            registeredOrders.push(item.registeredOrders);
            duvidasRegistradas.push(item.doubt);
            incidentesRegistrados.push(item.incidents);
        });
        console.log(ligEntrantes);
    },
    error: function(response){
        console.error(response);
    }
})

Chart.defaults.global.hover.intersect = false;
var estados = ["Acre","Alagoas","Amapá","Amazonas","Bahia","Ceará","Distrito Federal","Espírito Santo","Goiás","Maranhão","Mato Grosso","Mato Grosso do Sul","Minas Gerais","Pará","Paraíba","Paraná","Pernambuco","Piauí","Rio de Janeiro","Rio Grande do Norte","Rio Grande do Sul","Rondônia","Roraima","Santa Catarina","São Paulo","Sergipe","Tocantins"];
var regionChartCanvas = document.getElementById("regionChart").getContext("2d");
var regionChart = new Chart(regionChartCanvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: estados,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Ligações Entrantes',
            data: ligEntrantes,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'rgba(46, 204, 113,1.0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(46, 204, 113,1.0)',
            lineTension: 0
        },
        {
            label: 'Pedidos Registradas',
            data: registeredOrders,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'rgba(52, 152, 219,1.0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 152, 219,1.0)',
            lineTension: 0
        },
        {
            label: 'Dúvidas Registradas',
            data: duvidasRegistradas,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'rgba(52, 73, 94,1.0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 73, 94,1.0)',
            lineTension: 0
        },
        {
            label: 'Incidentes Registradas',
            data: incidentesRegistrados,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'rgba(231, 76, 60,1.0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(231, 76, 60,1.0)',
            lineTension: 0
        }]
    },
    options: {
        animation: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                autoSkip: false,
                beginAtZero: true
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: false
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'x',
            displayColors: true
        }
    },
});
};
```

However, when loading the page, the graph is not generated.
And when I move the mouse over the graph, I get the error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined --------- Chart.min.js:10
```

I've done tests with console.log in several parts of the code, and the Array is recognized normally.

Could someone please help me?
Grateful for disposal.

Answer (score -1):

ChartJS doesn't have "**regionChart**" support. Following link have the list of supported charts using ChartJS. I will suggest you to first implement a chart using hard coded values and when you are able to draw chart with hard coded then in next next step pull the data from the DB.

[ChartJS charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/)

Comment: regionChart is the name of my chart.

Comment: My bad, I just read the name and assumed that you want to draw this type of chat and didn't noticed the type. However, your code is working fine. I am able to run it and your chart is drawn. I have assigned hard coded values to your arrays "ligEntrantes, registeredOrders,...". Just do one thing do call your function on page load. I called it like $(document).ready(function() { charts(); } );